# UINavigationBar background image for both iOS6 and 7

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7

how would you setup a background image for the navigation bar of a navigation controller high 67 pixels?

I change its size with:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,67);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

In iOS6 it seems to work properly, even if there's a 1 pixel high white line under the status bar, whereas on iOS7 the image is covered by the status bar.

Any idea about how to handle such behavior?

Thanks,
DAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the background image of the navbar in this case didn't work for both iOS6 and 7. In the end I came up adding a child image to the nav bar.